# SoapUI how to verify json string is an array with all element are the same value

Tags: soapui, jsonpath

I use SoapUi 5.3.0 to test REST API.

My request return Json like below:

```
[
   {
      "name": "John",
      "online_status": "online"
   },
   {
      "name": "Marry",
      "online_status": "online"
   }
]
```

How can I use JsonPath expresstion to verify all "online_status" is online, not other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Script Assertion` for the same REST Request test step.

Here you go:

```
assert context.response, 'Response is null or empty'
def json = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(context.response)
//Get the online_status as Set; so unique value are stored
def result = json.collect{it.'online_status'} as Set
//It should be only one as expected
assert 1 == result.size()
//It should only have online
assert result == ['online'] as Set
```

If you want to try the script quickly, check <kbd>[Demo](https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5081655316316160)</kbd>

Comment: Thank you for your answer! In this case, I should use Script Assertion instead JsonPath expression, right?

Comment: @HiềnEBaby1, thats right. If that helps, [consider accepting as answered](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).